# Swift 3 Firebase Storage - Unable to upload

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I am trying to upload a UIImage file to firebase storage. I am struggling to figure out why the upload isn't completing, even with debugging.

I have created a Firebase app and set the storage rules to be publicly accessible.

The storage reference is defined in the properties as below:

```
var storageRef = FIRStorage.storage().reference().child("images/TestImage.png")
```

Then in the upload method (where meal.photo is a UIImage):

```
let uploadData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(meal.photo!)
let uploadTask = storageRef.put(uploadData!,metadata: nil){ metadata, error in
                if (error != nil) {
                    // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
                } else {
                    // Metadata contains file metadata such as size, content-type, and download URL.
                    let downloadURL = metadata!.downloadURL
                }
            }
```

I am not getting any build/run-time errors and I have confirmed that uploadData contains the file I wish to upload. However nothing is happening on running this method. Any ideas?

**EDIT**
I have included the entire snippet below for reference:

```
@IBAction func unwindToMealList(_ sender: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    if let sourceViewController = sender.source as? MealViewController, let meal = sourceViewController.meal {
        if let selectedIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            // Update an existing meal.
            meals[(selectedIndexPath as NSIndexPath).row] = meal
            tableView.reloadRows(at: [selectedIndexPath], with: .none)
        } else {
            // Add a new meal.
            let newIndexPath = IndexPath(row: meals.count, section: 0)
            meals.append(meal)

            let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
            dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM-dd-yyyy"
            let stringDate = dateFormatter.string(from: meal.date!)
            let mealItem = ["name": meal.name, "date": stringDate, "mealType": meal.mealType] as [String : Any]
            tableView.insertRows(at: [newIndexPath], with: .bottom)
            // Add meal to firebase database
            let mealRef = ref.child("meals")
            mealRef.setValue(mealItem)


            // Upload photo
           // let imagesRef = storageRef.child("images")
            let uploadData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(meal.photo!)
            let uploadTask = storageRef.put(uploadData!,metadata: nil){ metadata, error in
                if (error != nil) {
                    // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
                } else {
                    // Metadata contains file metadata such as size, content-type, and download URL.
                    let downloadURL = metadata!.downloadURL
                    print(downloadURL)
                }
            }
        }
        // Save the meals.
        saveMeals()
    }
}
```

Comment: The code looks correct. Do you get a download URL back? Without an error or any other information, it's going to be nearly impossible to debug.

Comment: Thanks @MikeMcDonald. No, I don't get a downloadURL back, the code doesn't seem to be entering into the upload method at all. What other information can I add that could help debug this? Apologies, quite new to this.

Comment: Can you either add a line `print(error)` to the place where it says `// Uh-oh, an error occurred!` or add a breakpoint there and confirm that there's no error? Unless the upload is never called (or you're offline for a sufficiently long time), I can't believe that neither of those options fire.

Comment: I've just tried that again, it isn't firing either of those

Comment: It turns out the file was just taking a long time to upload, apologies!

Answer (score 0):

Try this, i think you put the saveMeals() function to early, so, the upload method not called...

```
@IBAction func unwindToMealList(_ sender: UIStoryboardSegue) {
if let sourceViewController = sender.source as? MealViewController, let meal = sourceViewController.meal {
    if let selectedIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
        // Update an existing meal.
        meals[(selectedIndexPath as NSIndexPath).row] = meal
        tableView.reloadRows(at: [selectedIndexPath], with: .none)
    } else {
        // Add a new meal.
        let newIndexPath = IndexPath(row: meals.count, section: 0)
        meals.append(meal)

        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM-dd-yyyy"
        let stringDate = dateFormatter.string(from: meal.date!)
        let mealItem = ["name": meal.name, "date": stringDate, "mealType": meal.mealType] as [String : Any]
        tableView.insertRows(at: [newIndexPath], with: .bottom)
        // Add meal to firebase database
        let mealRef = ref.child("meals")
        mealRef.setValue(mealItem)


        // Upload photo
       // let imagesRef = storageRef.child("images")
        let uploadData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(meal.photo!)
        let uploadTask = storageRef.put(uploadData!,metadata: nil){ metadata, error in
            if (error != nil) {
                // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
            } else {
                // Metadata contains file metadata such as size, content-type, and download URL.
                let downloadURL = metadata!.downloadURL
                print(downloadURL)
                // New code, put your saveMeals function here.
                self.saveMeals()
            }
        }
    }
    // Old code, please remove this saveMeals function.
    // Save the meals.
    saveMeals()
}
```

}